# border-image doesn't render block's interior background in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

When I'm using the border-image property on a block, the interior portion of the block - where the content would go - remains transparent.

That's while my [sprite image](http://games4e.com/image-border_sprite.png) has a perfectly opaque white interior.

I can circumvent the problem by adding an internal div with the correct background, but that's unelegant. Is there a way to have the sprite's interior portion display without additional block workarounds? Thanks

[Problem demo page](http://games4e.com/border-test.php) (please view in Chrome)

Source:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    body { background: orange; padding: 30px; }
    .filling { background: white; height: inherit; margin-top: -16px; }
    .box {
        margin: auto auto;
        width: 200px; height: 200px;
        border-width: 31px 25px 25px 20px;
        -moz-border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;
        -webkit-border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;
        -o-border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;
        border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;
    }
</style>

<div class="box">
    <p>Why does the page background show through??</p>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="box">
    <div class="filling">
        <p>It should look like this!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you looking at this in?

Comment: Google Chrome (v21) is the problematic one; I assume this is a general webkit issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it is caused , probably a chrome bug.

Here is a fix however.

Add this to your `.box` css

```
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: white;
```

This will add a white background colour and clip it to its contents (including the padding).
More info on `background-clip` can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/).

---

**Working Example.**

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/u8ctc/

Comment: Thanks a lot! background-clip is new to me and completely solves my problem. I'm leaving the demo unfixed so that others can see the bug.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with the same problem, I just found a more direct fix: the **fill** property.
It seems that in a recent draft for border-image, the default behavior was set to keep the interior of the box *transparent*. If you want the interior to be rendered from your image sprite, you should add **fill**. For example,

Turn this:
border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;

Into this:
border-image: url(image-border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 **fill** / 31px 25px 25px 20px stretch;

From my tests this negates the need for adding a background and clipping it to padding-box (thanks for the answer though).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with the border while using the class with  attribute. The problem was solved easily when I changed the attribute to .  instead of:
CSS - img.pic1 {width...}
htm -

I used :

CSS - .pic1 {width...}
html =

that fixed all the image bugs I had...